# jQuery keypress not functioning on previously "hidden" element

Tags: jquery, keypress, hidden-field

I have scoured SO trying to find a solution (or piece one together), however I cannot find a definitive answer to my dilemma.

What I am attempting to do is the following:

```
$("#mini_search_input").keypress(function(event){

    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
        alert('my event!!');    
    }

});
```

Now, this snippet works great on the element if it enters the DOM at `display:block;`.  However, when it starts at `display:none;` and then I use a `.show()` to reveal it, the `keypress` stops functioning.  I've tested this in both Chrome and Firefox.

Is there something I am missing as to why that keypress won't bind to my element (no console errors -- just doesn't "fire") if I start the element as hidden?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this has anything to do with it's display css setting? it's more likely that you're adding it after binding the event, which means the event is not bound on that element. That or you have duplicate id's. css properties have no affect on whether or not an event gets triggered.

Comment: Either you have duplicate id's, and/or delegation really isn't needed and you just need to bind the event at the proper time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#mini_search_input', function (event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
        alert('my event!!');
    }
});
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

Comment: This is the most complete answer thank you ..  I would add one slight change, you forgot the hash `#` for the input identifier ..  clearly just typing too fast ;-)

Comment: @Zak yeah very fast on my keys ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its more possible that you're not just hiding & showing the element. Because, the event would fire if the element is present in DOM even if it has `display:none` & then made `display:block` later.

You're probably dynamically populating that element. In which case, use event delegation using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#mini_search_input', function(event){
    //Your code
});
```